# mvc3 razor view from different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

so in my profile controller page.
I have a method call create
inside the create method

```
   if (Convert.ToInt32(calBMI) >= 25)
            {
                return View("Index", Survey);
            }
```

I want to render the page to index of survey(survey is another controller take care of surveys), how do i do it to get it works,thanks!!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because i want to render the page to another controller's view

Comment: That one is evident. But why do you do that? What is the scenario you're trying to achieve? Because in most cases it should be achieved by some other way.

Comment: can you point out some other way for me

Comment: Not without me understanding what you really trying to achieve. Why do you need this?

Comment: return to another controller's view

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is pointless. "Return to another controller view" is a *method* to achieve something, some task, some goal. For example "every user must complete survey".

Answer (score 5):

```
 return View("~/Views/Survey/Index.cshtml", objSurvey);
```

Assuming `objSurvey` is your model/ViewModel object and `Survey/index` view is strongly typed to the type of `objSurvey` Model/ViewModel

**EDIT :** As per the comment, If your view is not strongly typed, you can ignore the second parameter

```
public ActionResult GetSomeThing()
{
   return View("~/Views/Survey/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: are you passing the instance of your model class ? What is your model class looks like ?

Comment: looks like you Survey is your class. Is it so ? then you need to pass the object of that class to the view.

Comment: my model class dont have survey, but i want to redirect to the views of survey

Comment: @user1155430: If your view is not strongly typed, you can ignore second parameter. See my updated answer.

Comment: Error 16 'xxx.Controllers.ProfilesController.Create(xxx.Models.Profile)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Wait !!! You said it is the Index view of Survey. Where did this Create action method coming from ?

Comment: that means it is not going inside the IF condition block (and not returning the Survey index view) and trying to return the Default view of Create action method.

Comment: i understand that, but how do i return the survey index view then, thanks

Comment: As per your original question, you wanted to return the survey index view only if, your IF condition is true. rite ? If you want to return that view always (no matter whatever the condition result is) move the return View statement outside the IF condition.

Comment: i tried that before, still give me error refer to not all code paths return a value –

Comment: It is very clear from the error message. If you can not figure out it, please post  your Action method code as a new question with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to share this view among multiple controllers, it should be in the `/Views/Shared/` folder.  There is a lack of good reasoning to use a view outside of either the controller folder or the shared folder.

Comment: my intention just want to click on the create method within the profile controller then render it to another controller's view

Comment: Then it sounds exactly like you want a shared view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can just redirect to list of surveys (if that's your intent).

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Survey");
```